# Optimizing spark sql Joins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to perform multiple joins in a Spark Sql job.. I have three data sources, lets call them a, b, c respectively. Each of them are read from S3 in plaintext CSV.

'a' and 'b' are large tables, with around 90m and 50m records respectively. Table 'c' is small, with just about 20k records.

The operation I am performing is

```
(a left join b where <filter something from a> group by <a.1,a.2,a.3,a.4>) 
left join c
```

The final op has around 620k records which is supposed to be the same as the number of filtered and grouped records in 'a' (the 'where' and 'group by' clauses above considerably reduce the amount of data from table 'a').

The operation is currently taking around 17 mins on my fairly powerful cluster. I would like to know if this can be reduced through optimization. Please advise.

Best Regards

Comment: Can you include the query plans (from web UI) to your question? Have you considered `c` dataset on your left side to join with `a` first and so cut the number of rows to deal with? What's the version of Spark? In Spark 2.2 you have cost-based optimizations that could help you a bit.

Comment: I would start asking question like ... where are the pain-points? What's the shuffle read/write size compared to the input size? Do you see straggler tasks? Is the data skewed? ... and taking it from there.

Comment: This is a good question: Spark `SQL` joins are *much* slower than `RDD` `union` plus `groupBy` (which can achieve similar results)